# How do I change my weblate site url

Tags: django, django-sites, weblate

I installed my own [weblate](https://weblate.org/) server somewhere, then I switched my nginx configuration to a domain name. I went into weblate's django admin, in sites section and updated the site entry to point to the right location.

I couldn't find anything related to this within `settings.py`. There's [a default site id](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-SITE_ID), but it's already set to 1.

[image: django-sites-change-site]

After doing this, urls to projects were still using old url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update site entry in django admin and **Restart the weblate django application**. After restarting weblate, the new url from database started working.

There is also this documented section:
https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/admin/management.html#changesite

Which should refresh website.